# Blowfish encryption and decryption not working

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

So I'm using a simple Blowfish encryption/decryption for an application I'm making. It works sometimes but isn't reliable.

### Form template being encrypted:

```
email@gmail.com

message

END
```

It works perfectly when I use an email like test1@gmail.com or test2@gmail.com.
When I use my personal email: tywemc@gmail.com, the form is encrypted but when it's decrypted, it returns î/ÅÝ®Îmail.comÄþ4œ’>L/ND

So it seems like it decrypts part of the form but not the whole thing and I can't figure out why. It seems to decrypts other forms partially with different real emails but still not completely. I'm using a static key within the Crypto.java class for simplicity.

I've tried to make sure the longer emails were causing it to not work because of a block size or string length issue but I don't think that's the problem.

### Crypto.java

```
package core;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto {

    private static String key = "key12345";

    public static String encrypt(String strClearText,String strKey) {
        String strData = "";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            System.out.println("Ëncryption keyspec: " + skeyspec.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
            strData = new String(encrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }


    public static String decrypt(String strEncrypted,String strKey) {
        String strData = "";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
            System.out.println("Decryption keyspec: " + skeyspec.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted.getBytes());
            strData = new String(decrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }
}
```

Should I use a different encryption type/method or is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

### Updated Code:

```
package core;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto {

    private static String key = "key12345";

    public static byte[] encrypt(String strClearText, String strKey) {
        byte[] encrypted = null;

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            System.out.println("Ëncryption keyspec: " + skeyspec.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
//          strData = new String(encrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }


    public static String decrypt(byte[] strEncrypted, String strKey) {
        String strData = "";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
            System.out.println("Decryption keyspec: " + skeyspec.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted);
            strData = new String(decrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }
}
```

`[B@164b077d` is what is passed in as `strEncrypted`.

Error
`javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Comment: `strData = new String(encrypted);` is wrong. You cannot reliably make a string of out arbitrary bytes. Either leave the result as a byte array or, if you *must* return a string, the properly encode the result using something like base64 encoding. There are a few other anti-patterns here that should not be present in reliable, portable, code.

Comment: so encode the byte array with base64 then create the String with the constructor?

Comment: That should work. And of course on decrypt you must first decode the string to get the bytes, then decrypt the bytes.

Comment: I'm gonna go with what you said first: have encrypt return a byte array and send that. Must I encode it then or not?

Comment: You only need to encode it if there is some reason to, for example you are sending it to the peer through an interface that only accepts character strings and not arbitrary bytes.

Comment: I have decrypt taking the byte array created from encrypt but I'm getting an error on `byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted);` Error: `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Comment: Post your new code.

Comment: `[B@164b077d` is not the ciphertext, it is just what a byte array produces if you directly call `toString()` on it, it's a reference to the object (in java, byte arrays have the type `[B`). Your code is OK (if insecure, because Java defaults to ECB mode), your bug however just migrated out of it. Oh, and Bruce Schneier advices against Blowfish. That's important for 2 reasons: 1. he's a top cryptographer and security expert and 2. he's the author of Blowfish.